# Como mudar a imagem ao trocar o status no banco de dados Mysql sem refresh com jquery

Tags: jquery

Tenho a seguinte listagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faria para que ao clicar no ícone de exclamação, alterasse para o ícone de check e vice-versa e alterasse também o status no banco de dados? O código PHP/Mysql sei fazer, mas o jquery que não saco muito. Como o status está vindo do BD, o código está dessa forma:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM documentos");

while($peListar = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){    

$statusDoc = ($peListar->StatusDocumentos == "A")?"<span style='color: red'><i class=\"fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg\" id=\"inativo\"></i></span>":"<span style='color: green'><i class=\"fas fa-check-circle fa-lg\" id=\"ativo\"></i></span>";
    echo $statusDoc;

}
```

Comment: Com qual id ou classe os ícones estão vindo do banco?

Comment: Perdão Jorge. Não consegui compreender sua pergunta. Você se refere ao id do banco?

Comment: Os ícones possuem `classe`? Ou algum outro atributo para poder ser identificado?

Comment: Não. Só o do próprio fontawesome

Comment: Na verdade nem precisa de Jquery nesse caso, basta chamar a action que está fazendo o update no botão que possui o ícone

Comment: Se quiser escrevo uma resposta mostrando a lógica.

Comment: Certo. Mas não gostaria que desse refresh na página.

Comment: Você me atentou a um detalhe que pode ter parecido vago. Alterei o meu título.

Comment: Para fazer com ajax, você vai precisar transformar o retorno do seu banco que mostra o status em json para conseguir pegar o retorno com jquery e mudar o icone

Comment: Certo. Só que não saco muito de jquery e Ajax. Poderia me mostrar um exemplo?

Comment: Você já está encondando o resultado do banco em um `json` no seu `php`? Se sim, poste o código de sua `action` e de como o resultado está sendo mostrado na página.

Comment: Ele está em PHP puro, usando o modo tradicional. Não estou usando json.

Comment: Para realizar o ajax você vai precisar transformar o retorno em json, pois o método precisa buscar o status no seu arquivo `php` para fazer a validação, entende?

Comment: Entendo.. mas não sei como fazer isso. Teria como me mostrar um exemplo que altero o meu código? Alterei meu post e coloquei um trecho de como ele está.

Comment: Poste o código de sua `action`. Basicamente você irá precisar da função [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Na verdade não estou usando formulários para buscar esse resultado. É um método de listagem na visualização dos documentos.

Comment: Coloque o código da listagem na pergunta pra facilitar quem quiser te ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer, mas não sei se é da forma correta e fiquem à vontade de me corrigir ;) Segue abaixo:

Listagem vinda do PHP

```
<?php
...
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM pe_documentos_pendentes");
while($peListar = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){
      $statusDoc = ($peListar->StatusDocumentos == "A")?"<a href='#!' class='alterar' data-id='".$peListar->IdDocumentos."' data-status='E' style='color: red'><i class=\"fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg\" id=\"inativo\"></i></span>":"<a href='#!' class='alterar' data-id='".$peListar->IdDocumentos."' data-status='A' style='color: green'><i class=\"fas fa-check-circle fa-lg\" id=\"ativo\"></i></a>";
      echo $statusDoc."<br>";
 }
...
?>
```

No Jquery, fiz dessa forma:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".alterar").click(function(){
      var posts = $(this).attr('data-id');
      var status = $(this).attr('data-status');
      $.post('alterar.php', {key: posts, status: status}, function(retorno){
             window.location.reload(true);
       });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Na página alterar.php:

```
mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE pe_documentos_pendentes SET StatusDocumentos = '".$_POST["status"]."' WHERE IdDocumentos = '".$_POST["key"]."';");
```

Answer (score 0):

Da maneira que fez está quase lá, porém você ainda está recarregando a página com `window.location.reload`. No seu arquivo PHP vc consegue fazer com que a lógica retorne o status atual, igual como fez na listagem, algo como:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE pe_documentos_pendentes SET StatusDocumentos = '".$_POST["status"]."' WHERE IdDocumentos = '".$_POST["key"]."';");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($count >= 1) {
 $response['success'] = true;
 echo json_encode($response);
}
```

E no Jquery

```
$.post('alterar.php', {key: posts, status: status}, function(retorno){
  //você possui o retorno da sua página alterar.php aqui, 
  data = $.parseJSON(retorno);
  alert(data.response);    
  //o que precisa fazer é apenas manipular essa resposta, 
  //criar seu ícone, substituir o atual no DOM, e fazer com que esse novo
  //ícone passe por esse mesmo evento de post
});
```